# Malloc implementation - confused

Tags: c

I'm trying to create my own malloc() for practice. I got the code below from this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422061/malloc-implementation)

```
typedef struct free_block {
    size_t size;
    struct free_block* next;
} free_block;

static free_block free_block_list_head = { 0, 0 };

// static const size_t overhead = sizeof(size_t);

static const size_t align_to = 16;

void* malloc(size_t size) {
    size = (size + sizeof(free_block) + (align_to - 1)) & ~ (align_to - 1);
    free_block* block = free_block_list_head.next;
    free_block** head = &(free_block_list_head.next);
    while (block != 0) {
        if (block->size >= size) {
            *head = block->next;
            return ((char*)block) + sizeof(free_block);
        }
        head = &(block->next);
        block = block->next;
    }

    block = (free_block*)sbrk(size);
    block->size = size;

    return ((char*)block) + sizeof(free_block);
}

void free(void* ptr) {
    free_block* block = (free_block*)(((char*)ptr) - sizeof(free_block ));
    block->next = free_block_list_head.next;
    free_block_list_head.next = block;
}
```

I'm confused about treating memory chunks as a linked list. It seems to me that we basicaly call sbrk() everytime we need memory and we check if some of the memory that we requested before wasn't freed in the meantime.

But we have no way of checking other memory chunks that belong to other processes, we only check the memory that we requested before and added to our linked list.

If this is the case, is this optimal? Is this how the standard malloc() works?
Is there a way for us to work with all the memory on the heap ?

Please explain like I'm 5, I'm having a hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: "Please explain like I'm 5" - Don't you get off your dirty hands immediately from my brand new keyboard!!!???

Comment: "chunks that belong to other processes" - you can't see any of the memory that belongs to other processes, only the kernel can (shared memory aside). `malloc` only deals with one process (and possibly multiple threads, but only one process).

Comment: "But we have no way of checking other memory chunks that belong to other processes". Umm, good thing, that. If you could just access other processes' memory, security would have a giant hole.

Comment: @Mat And suddenly it becomes clear :). Thanks :D

Comment: Read about virtual memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending process data segment doesn't affect other processes. On most (recent) architectures process memory model is flat, i.e. each process has a `virtual` address space (`2^32` or `2^64` bytes). When process requests extra memory (page), a `virtual` memory is added to process. In fact, that doesn't mean any physical memory allocation occurs, as `virtual` memory can be mapped to swap file, or unmapped before use altogether (address is given to process, but no actual resources assigned to it). Kernel takes care of mapping physical address to `virtual` one as per need/per resource availability.

What the algorithm does?

When user calls `malloc` the algorithm tries to find available empty block. In the beginning, there is none, so the algorithm tries to extend the process data segment.

However, you can see, that `free` doesn't release virtual memory (as it is not as trivial as allocating it), instead it adds this `released` block to a list of unused blocks.

So, when there are *prereleased* blocks, `malloc` attempts to reuse them instead of extendind the data segment.

Do standard `malloc`s work as above: no. The example you've provided is simple, yet really inefficient. There are many different algorithms available for memory management: small block heaps (when allocating data up to certain amount has a `O(1)` performance), thread-specific allocators (reducing congestion of accessing heap from multiple threads), allocators, that pre-allocate large chunks and then use them (similar to above, yet more efficient) and other.

You can try to goodle for "memory heap implementation" for more info