# Pointer array assignments change pointer value directly

Tags: c, pointers

There's multiple things that I might not potentially understand about this situation. I'm making my own version of malloc, where a provided sbrk function gives me an address to use to allocate memory on. This address goes into

```
void* heap = my_sbrk(stuff);
```

I need to put my recently acquired space that I can give out in an array. Since the heap pointer points to the start of my available space I do

```
freelist[7] = heap;
```

Now I can implement my function and it works perfectly until something does

```
freelist[7] = NULL;
```

which results in heap also becoming null

More generally if I want to change any pointer that is pointing to the beginning address of the heap, to point to NULL instead, heap also ends up pointing at NULL.

Is this a problem with memory allocation? Is it a problem with me misunderstanding how pointers work?

Edit: this is nothing like the 'duplicate question', where the poster wants to understand how memory is allocated. I want to understand why changing the value of an element of a pointer array also changes the object that element was pointing to.

namely, if I do

```
int* array;
int value = 8;
int* pointer = &value;
array[0] = pointer;
array[0] = NULL;
```

I would expect array[0] = NULL and *pointer = 8;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Malloc implementation - confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992389/malloc-implementation-confused) Is this an assignment? There was virtually the same question less than 2 weeks ago.

Comment: [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The last snippet doesn't initialize `array`, so accessing `array[0]` is undefined behavior, meaning that it could change `pointer`.