# Implementing malloc in multithreaded environment

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc, mutex, free

I want to implement malloc in a multithreaded environment, and I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422061/malloc-implementation).

After adding in mutex:

```
typedef struct free_block {
    size_t size;
    struct free_block* next;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} free_block;

void free_block_init(free_block *FB){
    pthread_mutex_init(&FB->lock, NULL);
}

static free_block free_block_list_head = { 0, 0 };
static const size_t overhead = sizeof(size_t);
static const size_t align_to = 8;

void* mymalloc(unsigned int size) {
    size = (size + sizeof(size_t) + (align_to - 1)) & ~ (align_to - 1);
    free_block* block = free_block_list_head.next;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&block->lock);
    free_block** head = &(free_block_list_head.next);
    while (block != 0) {
        if (block->size >= size) {
            *head = block->next;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&block->lock);
            return ((char*)block) + sizeof(size_t);
        }
        head = &(block->next);
        block = block->next;
    }
    block = (free_block*)sbrk(size);
    block->size = size;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&block->lock);
    return ((char*)block) + sizeof(size_t);
}

unsigned int myfree(void* ptr) {
    free_block* block = (free_block*)(((char*)ptr) - sizeof(size_t));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&block->lock);
    block->next = free_block_list_head.next;
    free_block_list_head.next = block;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&block->lock);
}
```

I'm only able to allocated memory to the first block, then a segmentation fault error. I don't know where my error is and I'm very new to threads and locks, so any sort of help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: So... if you delete the multithreaded bit, and do allocs/frees on a single thread it works fine?  Or not?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm don't really know how and where to add the locks to make it work.

Comment: I didn't read the code, was just asking...because you either have one of two problems; and which problem you have should guide your question.  If it's a malloc implementation problem, why bring mutexes into it?  If it's a mutex problem, why should we have to read a bunch of malloc code you know to work...instead of something much simpler to demonstrate the point?  Think about what it means to make a ["Minimal, Correct, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Some are willing to turn StackOverflow into a "we debug your code" service, but I favor helping people help themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&block->lock);
```

you haven't checked yet whether `block` is NULL. You would need to do the locking inside the loop.

Easier still, why not have just one mutex for your whole malloc - make it a static next to `free_block_list_head` then you can just lock it at the start of your function and unlock it after.

If you do stick with a per block mutex, remember to add space for the mutex to your calculations. You also need to make sure the pointer you pass back is pointing to memeory after your mutex in the data structure.

Edit: Also note: You also haven't called `free_block_init` anywhere.